# How to set chunk size of netCDF4 in python?

Tags: python, netcdf, chunks, chunking, netcdf4

I can see the default chunking setting in netCDF4 library, but I have no idea how to change the chunk size.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset    
volcgrp = Dataset('datasets/volcano.nc', 'r')
data = volcgrp.variables['abso4']
print data.shape
print data.chunking()
>(8, 96, 192)
>[1, 96, 192]
```

Is there anyone who can help with the setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html) to read the netcdf file and set chunks, e.g.

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('/datasets/volcano.nc', chunks={'time': 10})
```

Comment: This is an old question + answer. Maybe it's worth revisiting. Xarray will do chunking in-memory. What about writing the new array + chunking layout to a NetCDF file via `.to_necdf()`? Will it preserve information about chunking in the metadata?

Answer (score 3):

It is a little unclear what you are trying to do. `data.chunking()` tells you the chunksize of the variable as stored in the file. If you would like to change this, you need to re-write the file on disk, setting the chunksize for each variable. With the `netCDF4` library, you can do this with the `chunksizes` keword argument to `netCDF4.CreateVariable()`. Documentation found here:

http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset.createVariable

Comment: there is a small but important typo here, the correct keyword is chunksizes and not chunksize.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer I think. The chunks in the question refer to the chunks inside the netcdf-file, which is different from the chunks used by `xarray` as mentioned in the answer by @N1B4. In `xarray` you could see the "internal" chunks like this `ds["abso4"].encoding["chunksizes"]`.